# SQL statement ‘IN’ contains too many expressions

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I use JDBC to retrieve Oracle database by ‘IN’ statement. But there are too many expressions, about >1000.
It looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE name IN (?, ?, ?......); --More than 1000 question signal
```

It causes ‘*syntax error or access rule violation*’ which means ‘*maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000*’.

Do I have to do retrieve operation many times (for example, using 100 ‘?’ and retrieve 10 times) and merge the lists? 
Any better solution? Thanks!

Edit:
I have no chance to modify database which is not my work of art.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your scenario a bit as well? What kind of scenario has 1000+ specific values being passed to a select query? Maybe understanding that might help come up with a alternate solution..

Comment: Aahh, StackOverflow, such fertile ground for The Daily WTF :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: What is 'WTF' for? 'World Taekwondo Federation'?

Comment: It _could_ stand for "Worse Than Failure" but that's the politically correct term. Its old name (and what anyone who has followed it for a while still calls it) is "What The F***?": http://thedailywtf.com/

Comment: @卢声远 Shengyuan Lu, why do you have more than 1000 values to insert into your select statement?

Comment: @Mark: This is the question I want to ask the original author of the code:) The '1000 values' are returned from other complex method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd be rethinking the logic of why you would need to pass in that many things to look for. Perhaps there is a different way to specify what you are looking for.

Alternatively, another option is to create a temporary table, load the keys you are looking for into the table and then do a join between the data table and the table of keys. Then you won't need a in() clause.

Comment: If there's more than 1000 entries, they almost certainly came from the database in the first place.  Just paste whatever query created them right into the IN clause.

Comment: temporary table is a decent way.   and Joel also inspired me to filter the list by Java: to retrieve data without IN, then filter the list.    Actually most records of MyTable are expected ones.

Answer (score 1):

If you have that many expressions, it may be easier to insert them into a temp table, then query MyTable against the temp.

Answer (score 1):

the brute force way around this is

```
(foo in (1,4,8,12,1000))  or (foo in (2333,2443,2453,4665))
```

where each in clause is less than 1000

Of course the chances of your query being performant isn't very good.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has issues with an IN list >~1000.

1. JOIN: create a (optionally temporary) table with the list items and join the table into your query.  If you use a more durable table then put a session identifier as a key.  Sounds like this may not work as you have no access to the schema?
2. UNION (ALL): break out your list into under 1000, and union multiple selects,
3. OR: (already mentioned) or your list

Personally, I prefer a join for this type of stuff.